# How to access keycloak with the admin-client?

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I'm trying to change roles of a user in keycloak with the keycloak-admin-client in a spring boot application, but I can't even instanciate keycloak.

I'm trying to get the keycloak server here, but Im getting a InstantiationError

```
    String serverUrl = "http://localhost:8080/auth";
    String realm = "User-Service-Realm";
    String clientId = "admin-cli";

    Keycloak keycloak = Keycloak.getInstance(
      serverUrl,
      realm,
      "admin",
      "admin",
      clientId);
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InstantiationError: org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak.<init>(Keycloak.java:58)
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak.getInstance(Keycloak.java:106)
    at de.uni.stuttgart.isw.ccm.userservice.api.KeycloakAdminClientExample.main(KeycloakAdminClientExample.java:31)
```

Apparently its a problem with the admin-client itself, since the keycloak builder is based on the resteasyclientbuilder. 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have incompatible libraries or library versions. The error message complains that `ResteasyClientBuilder` is abstract. That not the case in our working project.

So as a reference, here is an extract from our gradle file so you can see a working combination of library versions:

```
implementation 'org.keycloak:keycloak-admin-client:6.0.1'
implementation 'javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0'
implementation 'org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:3.6.3.Final'
implementation 'org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client:3.6.3.Final'
implementation 'org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jackson2-provider:3.6.3.Final'
```

**Update**:

`ResteasyClientBuilder` has become an abstract class with version 4.0 of *RESTEasy*. So it looks as if you are using version 4.x, while Keycloak expects 3.x.

Comment: Quarkus users might want to follow these issues:

- https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6350
- https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-12285

Since Quarkus relies on RESTEasy 4.x, there is currently no real solution for this issue.